# Add content in a div tag upon clicking next or prev buttons for tasks checked as Mark for Review

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Suppose, I have a list of tasks to which user can navigate via Prev and Next button. User will select a check box "Mark for Review". Based upon this action two div tags namely "Marked For Review" and "Not Marked for Review" are populated or updated containing task# hyperlink.

**My issue is upon selecting checkbox, the div sections are not getting updated.**
It gets initialize, however it does not respond to changes done later on.

The current code only contains only one div tag for displaying marked for review tasks.

The html source

```
    <h3>Tasks</h3>

    <div>
        <label data-bind="text: titleHolder()"></label>
        <br>
        <input type = "checkbox" data-bind="checked: isMarked">Mark For Review</input>
        <br>
        <button data-bind="click: prevItem">Prev</button>
        <button data-bind="click: nextItem">Next</button>
    </div>


    <div name= "markedForReview" data-bind="foreach: markedTasks()">
        <a href="#" >Some random text to make sure if array gets updated then this should display</a>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.1.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/ViewModelClient.js'></script>
</body>
```

My view model

```
function Task(data) {
this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
this.isMark = ko.observable(data.isMark);
}

function TaskListViewModel() {

var self = this;
self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
self.itemIndex = ko.observable();
self.titleHolder = ko.observable();
self.isMarked = ko.observable();

self.itemIndex(0);

self.markedTasks = ko.observableArray([]);

//Manually added tasks
self.tasks.push(new Task({title: "Task 1", isMark: false}));
self.tasks.push(new Task({title: "Task 2", isMark: false}));
self.tasks.push(new Task({title: "Task 3", isMark: false}));
self.tasks.push(new Task({title: "Task 4", isMark: false}));

self.titleHolder(self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].title);

self.nextItem = function(){

    //Update in the json data.
    self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark = self.isMarked();

    //If its been marked as true, then push the element in markedTasks array
    if (self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark == true){
        self.markedTasks().push(new Task(self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()]));
    }

    //Increment item index
    self.itemIndex(self.itemIndex() + 1);

    //To wrap around
    if (self.itemIndex() === self.tasks().length )
        self.itemIndex(0);

    //Update the task
    self.titleHolder(self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].title);

    //Load the correct state of mark for review checkbox
    if (self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark == true)
        self.isMarked(true);
    else{
        self.isMarked(false);
        self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark = false;
        }



};

self.prevItem = function(){

    //Update in the json data.
    self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark = self.isMarked();

    ////If its been marked as true, then push the element in markedTasks array
    if (self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark == true){
        self.markedTasks().push(new Task(self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()]));
    }       

    //Decrement item array
    self.itemIndex(self.itemIndex() - 1);

    //To wrap around
    if (self.itemIndex() === -1 )
        self.itemIndex(self.tasks().length - 1);

    //Update the task
    self.titleHolder(self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].title);

    //Load the correct state of mark for review checkbox
    if (self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark == true)
        self.isMarked(true);
    else{
        self.isMarked(false);
        self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()].isMark = false;
        }
};



}

ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());
```

Comment: a bit too much code there - can you provide a jsfiddle with simplified content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ko.computed`s instead to keep track of the current item and which items are marked
[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUram/)

```
    ...
    self.currentItem = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.tasks()[self.itemIndex()];
    }, this);
    self.markedTasks = ko.computed(function(){
        var markedTasksArray = [];
        $(self.tasks()).each(function(i,e){
            if (e.isMark() == true) markedTasksArray.push(e);
        });
        return markedTasksArray;
    }, this);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks you helped a lot. I have updated the code, on clicking Mark For Review checkbox the link gets displayed with Task#. Now, I am stuck on how to update the task title when user click on the link. Here is JS fiddle for it [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DashmeetSingh/aewJA/)

Comment: No need. Finally I figured it out. I m finally getting hang of KnockoutJs. :)